# IBM Worklight - How to disconnect a client?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I can find `WL.Client.connect` to connect a client - so far so good. How can I do the opposite however? (I have good reason to do this, rest assured.)

Comment: Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think that for this purpose, what you'd actually need to do is to "restart the session" with the server. Try using `WL.Client.ReloadApp`.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean by disconnect? WL app does not maintain an open connection. HTTP connection is closed each time response is returned from a server. Do you mean WL.Client.logout() ?